# How is it possible to model in a database many different products?

Tags: mysql, eav

For example, a smartphone might have attributes such as RAM and camera resolution, whereas a fridge has way different attributes. Is there a way to store these data in a relational database?

Comment: Read about EAV pattern.

Comment: There's good and bad ways to do [EAV](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav), so keep in mind which data needs to be searched for and which is just retrieved. Note MySQL-8.0 and MariaDB-10.2(?) you can create virtual columns and index expressions on these.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some columns that are common to almost all products:  Price, SKU, Manufacturer, etc.  Those may as well be columns.  The rest can be put into a JSON string.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav